# Does magic immunity have any impact on a monster's DR in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage-reduction, immunities

My players will encounter a Flesh Golem. It has DR 5/adamantine and is immune to magic (and othe construct traits). My players possess each +1 magic weapons and they will use it. I can imagine that they will not help with the DR in that case. After all, most spells will not affect tis creature and my question is will the weapons deal damage at all?

Although it's CR 7, it looks pretty tough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The weapons will deal their normal, magically-enhanced damage.  Minus 5, for the golem's DR, unless the weapons are also adamantine.**  Immunity to magic doesn't automatically destroy all magic the golem comes into contact with, it just can't be directly affected by magical effects.

[PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/golem/golem-flesh) wrote:

> Immunity to Magic (Ex)
>
> A flesh golem is *immune to any spell or spell-like ability **that allows spell resistance**.* In addition, certain spells and effects function differently against the creature...

Emphasis mine.

If something allows spell resistance, immunity to magic functions like infinite spell resistance against it.  Things that aren't stopped by spell resistance (like sword swings, *acid arrows*, and being crushed under a ton of solid rock during an *earthquake* spell) aren't stopped by immunity to magic.  It also specifically only works against spells and spell-like abilities, so it doesn't stop things like dragon breath or magic swords.

So we've established that "immune to magic" doesn't turn off a magic weapon's +1.  What does that mean for the golem's DR?  In this case, nothing.

[PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Overcoming-DR) wrote:

> Weapons with an enhancement bonus of +3 or greater can ignore some types of damage reduction, regardless of their actual material or alignment. The following table shows what type of enhancement bonus is needed to overcome some common types of damage reduction.
>
> Cold iron / silver     +3
>
> Adamantine*     +4
>
> Alignment-based     +5

So the weapons would need to be +4 to bypass the golem's DR 5/adamantine.  If they *were* +4, they would overcome the DR despite the golem's immune to magic trait; but it's a moot point since they're only +1 weapons to start with, therefore they only overcome DR /magic (and the various damage types for their weapon types).

Comment: I looked up Immunity to Magic yesterday but thanks.

Comment: @masche it's just standard procedure to cite support for your answers.  The important part is the "...that allows spell resistance." part.  I'll go emphasize it.

Comment: About DR: Until now i thought magic wepons helps with DR its enchantment bonus. Thats why I asked in this case.

Comment: @Masche oh, you're asking about the weapon's ability to bypass DR?  I'll add that to my answer (as soon as I find it...), sorry I didn't get that the first time, it's really late.

Comment: Thats bull****, how does Paizo expect a 6th lvl char to have a +4 weapon or admantine wepons. The fighter in the parte have one adamantine dagger. ONE! I smell TPK. -_-

Comment: @masche They don't expect 6th level players to have adamant weapons. They expect a 6th level character to beat a Flesh Golem by the age-old strategy of 'Just hit it harder'.

Comment: I'm talking about the Scarecrow in the Rise of the Rune Lords advanture path- ;-) TPK  still is imminent ... just a few (un-)lucky rolls with that syythe.

Comment: @masche DR 5 isn't too hard to just hit through, and yeah, randomness hates players.  A x4 crit weapon against PCs is awesome unless it actually crits :P  A PC that makes their Knowledge check should discover its weakness to cold and fire and make the fight much easier.  The *slow* effect from any cold or fire spell - even *ray of frost* or *burning hands* penalizes the Scarecrow's move speed, AC, and attack rolls, and prevents a full attack.  He's a miniboss for sure, but shouldn't be THAT difficult.  *Acid arrow* at CL 6 is 6d4 bypassing DR, the fighter can improvise a two-hander, etc.

Comment: @ gatherer818 The Scarecrow is a Flesh Golem and therefore Immune to magic. Ray of Frost and Burnig Hands won't work.

Well. the  Scarecrow's demise was a large lion (animal companion of our Druid) who succeded his grapple 3 times in a row. The rest of the party just went flanking and dealt huge amounts  of damage with power attack and similar feats. All my worries for nothing. -_-
Thank you, fellow gamers!

Comment: @masche all fire and cold spells work on flesh golems, but produce a 2d6 round *slow* effect instead of damage